# trigger inotify event over NFS on Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, nfs, inotify

Can I trigger a filesystem event on Linux, without an actual file change?
Is there some system call that acts like the file was written?
Is that even possible?

I have a NFS share mounted and want to get `inotify` events in the virtual machine, when a file changes on the server site.

It seems `inotify` doesn't work with NFS.
Is there any network filesystem that supports `inotify`?

It's easy to monitor the events on the server site, but how can I trigger the events on the client?  At that moment I do a simple `touch`, but that's not ideal.

*(the use case is for local development with docker (boot2docker, OS X.)*

Comment: Perhaps you could try creating (and subsequently removing?) a symlink?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's just not a feature.

You could implement some sort of semaphore thing by using incrond to monitor the local filesystem, then do something (touch a file, trigger a script, etc.) on the remote machine to tell it there's been an update, but there's no native functionality in NFS.

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using Docker for Mac. I still use NFS because of the bad file sharing performence with osxfs. I have written a sublime text 3 plugin, to do the touch automatically, this solves my use case.

- sublime text 3 plugin: [sublime_d4m](https://github.com/yvess/sublime_d4m)
- nfs server in docker for mac: [d4m-nfs](https://github.com/IFSight/d4m-nfs)